# Tengo este error cuando intento generar el apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

```sh
flutter build apk  --release
```

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\WorkSpace\Flutter\flutter_ui_planets\android\app\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       9.6s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de la versión 2 de Flutter soporta Null safety.
Seguramente debes chequer que librerias de las que utilizas no lo soportan aún.
Lo primero sería confirmar esto.
Puedes ejecutar `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety` para saber con precisión que libreria tiene el problema.

Llegado ese punto o bien actualizar esa libreria, si soporta Null Safety o buscar otra solución como utilizar una versión anterior de Flutter para poder publicar tu app sin esta característica pero sin problemas.

Saludos